# Compile .NET app that uses Bond in Linux Docker container

Tags: .net, bond

I'm trying to make a CD for a library that uses Bond. It compiles perfectly locally but it seems like I can't compile it in a Docker image. I'm getting the error below. It suggests that I need to install Bond tools. I can't find an image that would have them installed and I also can't find the way to install them. (I did try `apt-get` and `nuget install`.) The Bond GitHub project only shows how to compile them. How can I solve that?

I'm using the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk. It compiles everything that don't contain Bond very well.

````
        MSBuild version 17.5.0-preview-23061-01+040e2a90e for .NET
          Determining projects to restore...
          Restored /var/workdir/aaa/bbb.csproj (in 11.23 sec).
          /bin/sh: 2: /tmp/MSBuildTemproot/tmp07e2245471a6416d99ff3965ff6cc96e.exec.cmd: /app/.nuget/packages/bond.csharp/9.0.5/build/../tools/gbc.exe: Exec format error
        /app/.nuget/packages/bond.csharp/9.0.5/build/Common.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: The command ""/app/.nuget/packages/bond.csharp/9.0.5/build/../tools/gbc.exe" c# --import-dir="/app/.nuget/packages/bond.csharp/9.0.5/build/../tools/inc"  --jobs=-2 --namespace=bond=Bond --output-dir="obj/Release/netstandard2.1/" --using="DateTime=System.DateTime" @"obj/Release/netstandard2.1/bonddefaultcodegen.in"" exited with code 126. [/var/workdir/aaa/bbb.csproj]
        
        Build FAILED.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the Windows version of gbc on Linux. As of March 2023, there is no pre-compiled version of gbc for Linux. The gbc included in the NuGet packages is only for Windows.

You will need to compile gbc yourself targeting Linux following the instructions in [Bond's README](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/blob/master/README.md) and set [the environment variable (or MSBuild property) `BOND_COMPILER_PATH`](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/blob/b13fee1b760119a79d038e43fb05d88e800fc7e5/cs/build/nuget/Common.targets#L8) to the path to the directory that contains the gbc that you have built.

This is a known gap in Bond's tooling. See its GitHub [issue #940, gbc for Linux?](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/issues/940) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - custom dockerfile with compilcation of bond was needed - works now.